# Aristotle on forgiveness?

Tags: ethics, aristotle, friendship

Discussing "complaints" in friendship ([*Ethics* book 8](https://isidore.co/aquinas/Ethics8.htm#13)), Aristotle does not mention the role of forgiveness in resolving such complaints (ἐγκλήματα) or quarrels (μέμψεις).

Does Aristotle discuss forgiveness elsewhere in his works?

Comment: It's perhaps noteworthy that forgiveness finds no place in Aristotle's canon of virtues in NE, III.6 - IV.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Rhetoric* [2.3](https://archive.org/details/worksofaristotle11arisuoft/page/n96/mode/1up), Aristotle discusses calmness (πραότης): among other things, calmness is directed "towards those who admit their fault and are sorry: since we accept their grief at what they have done as satisfaction, and cease to be angry" ([1380a](http://data.perseus.org/citations/urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0086.tlg038.perseus-eng1:2.3.5)).

In *Nicomachean Ethics* [3.1](https://archive.org/details/workstranslatedi09arisuoft/page/n57/mode/1up), Aristotle discusses voluntary and involuntary acts, and adds ([1110b](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0086.tlg010.perseus-eng1:1110b)-1111a) that involuntary acts committed out of ignorance are more likely to receive "mercy and forgiveness" (ἔλεος καὶ συγγνώμη).

(Cited and analyzed in David Konstan, *Before Forgiveness*, [23](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=KSvVDfUkpRcC&lpg=PP1&hl=iw&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q&f=false)-30.)